# Excel Activex Listbox to open on rectangle click, close when listbox not in focus, and output selections to cell

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, activex

I have a rectangle with no fill located over cell A1 to give the impression that A1 triggers the event.

The code for this rectangle opens and closes an ActiveX Listbox on click.
The selections are output to a cell A1 named "ListBoxOutput" seperated by commas.
I would instead like the Listbox to close when clicking anywhere outside the Listbox and for the last selection to have no comma after it.

This is the code:

```
Sub Rectangle3_Click()

    Dim xSelShp As Shape, xSelLst As Variant, I, J As Integer
    Dim xV As String
    Set xSelShp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    Set xLstBox = ActiveSheet.ListBox1
        If xLstBox.Visible = False Then
            xLstBox.Visible = True
            xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
            xStr = ""
            xStr = Range("ListBoxOutput").Value
     
            If xStr <> "" Then
                xArr = Split(xStr, ", ")
                For I = xLstBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                xV = xLstBox.List(I)
                For J = 0 To UBound(xArr)
            
                If xArr(J) = xV Then
                    xLstBox.Selected(I) = True
                    Exit For
                End If
        
                Next
                Next I
            End If
        
            Else
                xLstBox.Visible = False
                xSelShp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
                For I = xLstBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                
                If xLstBox.Selected(I) = True Then
                    xSelLst = xLstBox.List(I) & ", " & xSelLst
                End If
                
                Next I
                    If xSelLst <> "" Then
                        Range("ListBoxOutput") = Mid(xSelLst, 1, Len(xSelLst) - 1)
                    Else
                        Range("ListBoxOutput") = ""
                    End If
            End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that `Worksheet_SelectionChange` can do this work. Did you try it?

Comment: I havent. I'm very new to this and it has taken me a while just to get this code working for me. I'm not sure how to adapt it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Worksheet_SelectionChange place the code in the `Worksheet code module`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.ListBox1
        If Target(1).Address = "$A$1" Then
            .Visible = True
        Else
            .Visible = False
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(i) Then txt = txt & "," & .List(i)
            Next
            [A1] = Mid(txt, 2)  'remove first comma and output to A1 cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Before (cursor on A1):
[image]
After (cursor on A2):
[image]

Comment: I am not using a UserForm, just a ListBox. Does this still apply?

Comment: General idea is the same

Comment: I have never used UserForm before but this might still be ok If I can lock it in position. I have tried the code and it works however I cant get the selected items in list to to show in the cell. Where is the output going?

Comment: In my example output going to Immediate window in VBE for debugging purpose: `Debug.Print "selected: " & txt`

Comment: @ayecee Corrected the code for ListBox, placed directly on the Worksheet

Comment: This is so concise and works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure if this needs to be a new question. Just trying to change the If statement so that  selecting A1 (or any other cell) can change visibility of the ListBox to False. I have tried `If Target(1).Address = "$A$1" And .Visible = False Then .Visible = True Else .Visible = False`. Seems logical to me but not working.

Comment: For the SelectionChange event to be triggered, you must change the selection on the sheet. If you want to call SelectionChange repeatedly when selecting the same cell, you can immediately move the cursor to another cell after the first selection, then this event will occur when you select the starting cell again. For example, after selecting A1, run `[B1].Select` (B1, let's assume, is under the ListBox and not visible). To avoid unnecessarily triggering SelectionChange during this move, execute `Application.EnableEvents = False` before and `... = True` after the specified operation.

Comment: I have entered `Application.EnableEvents = False`  `[A2].Select` `Application.EnableEvents = True` After the EndIf and before the End With. It works to create a Toggle effect on A1 however when trying to select any other cell on the sheet, A2 is always selected.

Comment: @ayecee Place it between `.Visible = True` and `Else`

Comment: This works one time, ie. click A1 to open, Click A1 or anywhere to close, but click A1 a second time and it doesnt open. I must click another cell then A1 again to open. Also on the first time, if clicking "open" then "close" too fast it enters into cell A2.

Comment: @ayecee In the latter case, the event Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick is triggered, and if you want to prevent entering a cell, assign `Cancel=True` in this procedure

Comment: That worked for the double click, thanks for all your help. I have posted the other issue as a new question.